# Перебор всех возможных сумм массива с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите с **алгоритмом** для программы

> Есть массив из n чисел, необходимо создать новый массив, в котором будут выведены все суммы исходного массива.
>
> Например:
>
> На вход:
>
> ```
> 3
> 2 3 5
> ```
>
> На выход:
>
> ```
> 2 3 5 5 7 8 10
> ```
>
> На вход:
>
> ```
> 4 
> 6 7 2 10
> ```
>
> На выход:
>
> ```
> 6 7 2 10 13 8 16 9 17 12 15 23 19 25
> ```

Понимаю, что нужно использовать рекурсию, но не знаю, как это сделать

Comment: Генерируете все выборки длинной от 1 до n из элементов массива, считаете сумму каждой выборки, заносите в массив.

Comment: @VTT как сгенерировать все выборки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из возможных классических подходов перебора - это использование рекурсии. Вот код, который рекурсивно считает суммы всех возможных комбинаций массива

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int sum(std::vector<int>& result, const std::vector<int>& v, int index, int curSum)
{
    if (index < v.size())
    {
        curSum += v[index];
        for (int i = index + 1; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {
            int res = sum(result, v, i, curSum);
            result.push_back(res);
        }
    }
    return curSum;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 6, 7, 2, 10 };

    std::vector<int> result;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        int res = sum(result, v, i, 0);
        result.push_back(res);
    }

    for (const int s : result)
        std::cout << s << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

На выходе имеем:

> 25 15 23 13 18 8 16 6 19 9 17 7 12 2 10

Comment: господин минусующий, будьте добры озвучить свои доводы.

Answer (score 0):

Выписка возможных выборок имеет сложность экспоненциальную **O(2^N)**. Можно представлять конкретную выборку как массив логических значений **true**/**false**. Например как `std::vector<bool>`. Перебор возможных выборок с помощью рекурсии нагружает стек лишней информацией. Можно перебирать все выборки с помощью собственной процедуры инкремента `{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}`. Те , кто дружит с языком C не любят вектора. Они пользуются массивом `unsigned int m[(N / (sizeof(unsigned int)*8))+1]`. Если аккуратно написать инкремент данного вектора, это даст максимальную скорость.

Comment: Максимальную скорость дас код Грея - не надо будет много считать, только один элемент прибавить или отнять.

Answer (score 0):

Решала подобную задачу реальную для бухгалтерии в Excel. 
Был список работников с суммами к выдаче зп. 
Зп была выдана по нескольким ведомостям. От ведомостей остались только итоговые суммы.
Нужно было распределить работников по нескольким ведомостям. Вручную это никому в отделе не удалось сделать.
Решила в Excel с помощью нулей и единиц. Нечто подобное тому, что на картинке ниже.
Кстати автор вопроса забыл в промежуточных суммах указать 18

[image: Удобно эту задачу решать в Excel, вот пример]

Comment: Это вообще как к вопросу относится?